# Google PageSpeed Insight give me an error message: Unable to resolve. Try checking the URL for validity

Tags: web-crawler

I got an error message from Google PageSpeed Insight when testing my site.

> Unable to resolve https://www.shoppersgossip.com/. Try checking the URL for validity.

I'm afraid it will affect SEO.

Hostinger inbuilt speed test metric give me an error message "Avoid too many redirection". The website was redirected from non www version to www version last month.

What could be the possible problem behind this? I can test it from gt Metrix and Pingdom but not from Google Page Speed Insight.

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Comment: Looks all good here.

Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/0JYyra4.png

Are you still experiencing this error?

Comment: My end result https://imgur.com/a/5paEcjs from India

Comment: I guess it's a temporary. Check the Core Web Vitals section of the site's GSC profile to make sure it is checking correctly.